# it does not hold its value outside the clock edge

Tags: vhdl

i am pretty new to vhdl. I am writing a code to display different type of rgb pattern onto the de2-115 t-pad by the use of the switches. Here are the following code i wrote.I have checked it for many times,but Quartus always report the error.i would appreciate it if you can help me.

```
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

       entity rgb is
           port (
                  sw                : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
                      iclk                  : in std_logic:= '0';
                      iRST_n                : in std_logic;
                      x_cnt             : in std_logic_vector (10 downto 0);
                      y_cnt             : in std_logic_vector (10 downto 0);
                  data1,data2,data3  : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                  );
      end rgb;

      architecture behave of rgb is  
        begin

         process(RGB, iclk,iRST_n,x_cnt,y_cnt)
          begin

    if iRST_n = '0' then      -- line of error
            data1 <= "00000000"; 
            data2 <= "00000000"; -- BLACK
          data3 <= "00000000";  

       elsif (rising_edge(iclk)) then   

    if (rgb = "001") then --RGB

          if (y_cnt<=209) then
            data1 <= "11111111"; -- RED
            data2 <= "00000000"; 
          data3 <= "00000000";  

          elsif (y_cnt>209 and y_cnt<=418) then
            data1 <= "00000000"; 
            data2 <= "11111111"; -- GREEN
          data3 <= "00000000";  

          elsif  (y_cnt> 418) then
            data1 <= "00000000"; 
            data2 <= "00000000"; 
          data3 <= "11111111";  --BLUE
                 end if;
                 end if;

    elsif(rgb ="010") then --RBGBB
          if (x_cnt<=184) then
            data1 <= "11111111"; 
            data2 <= "00000000"; 
          data3 <= "00000000";  

          elsif (x_cnt>=234 and x_cnt<=393) then
            data1 <= "00000000"; 
            data2 <= "11111111"; 
          data3 <= "00000000";  

          elsif  (x_cnt>= 443) then
            data1 <= "00000000"; 
            data2 <= "00000000"; 
          data3 <= "11111111";  
    end if;

    end process;

     end behave;
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by indenting the code according to the control structures.  This will reveal that the final `elsif(rgb ="010") then` is not under the `rising_edge(iclk)`, thus update may occur "outside the clock edge", as the error message says.

Also, there is no `rgb` signal or port, thus using this like `rgb = "001"` will also result in error.

Also, the `if` and `end if` are not balanced.

Probably more issues, but just for a start...

Answer (score 1):

You had the end if's messed up in two places and several places were using the indentifier `rgb` when you should have been using `sw`.

A little indentation as Morten writes and fixing the names and end ifs:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity rgb is
    port (
        sw:                 in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        iclk:               in  std_logic := '0';
        iRST_n:             in  std_logic;
        x_cnt:              in  std_logic_vector (10 downto 0);
        y_cnt:              in  std_logic_vector (10 downto 0);
        data1,data2,data3:  out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
    );
end entity rgb;

architecture behave of rgb is  
begin

L1:
    process (sw, iclk, iRST_n, x_cnt, y_cnt)
    begin
        if iRST_n = '0' then      -- line of error
            data1 <= "00000000"; 
            data2 <= "00000000"; -- BLACK
            data3 <= "00000000";  
       elsif rising_edge(iclk) then   
           if sw = "001" then --RGB
               if y_cnt <= 209 then
                   data1 <= "11111111"; -- RED
                   data2 <= "00000000"; 
                   data3 <= "00000000";  
               elsif  y_cnt > 209 and y_cnt <= 418 then
                   data1 <= "00000000"; 
                   data2 <= "11111111"; -- GREEN
                   data3 <= "00000000";  
               elsif  y_cnt > 418 then
                   data1 <= "00000000"; 
                   data2 <= "00000000"; 
                   data3 <= "11111111";  --BLUE
               end if;
           elsif sw = "010" then --RBGBB
                if  x_cnt <= 184 then
                    data1 <= "11111111"; 
                    data2 <= "00000000"; 
                    data3 <= "00000000";  
                elsif x_cnt >= 234 and x_cnt <= 393 then
                    data1 <= "00000000"; 
                    data2 <= "11111111"; 
                    data3 <= "00000000";  
                elsif  (x_cnt>= 443) then
                    data1 <= "00000000"; 
                    data2 <= "00000000"; 
                    data3 <= "11111111";  
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture behave;
```

Using package numeric_std_unsigned is my personal choice.  Without checking using package std_logic_unsigned instead probably works just fine.  Package numeric_std_unsigned is part of the -2008 VHDL standard and is intended to replace std_logic_unsigned which is from a particular vendor and not part of the standard (yet still widely used, -2008 has had slow uptake).

And with these changes your code analyzes and elaborates.